# custom properties in liquibase.properties file

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase 2.0.5 and my properties file looks like below

```
#liquibase.properties
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
username=myschama
password=myschama
masterUsername=system
masterPassword=system
```

I want to use system user to create myschema user. Currently, I get the following error.

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'masterUsername'
SEVERE 12/21/17 12:59 PM:liquibase: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'masterUsername'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unknown parameter: 'masterUsername'
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parsePropertiesFile(Main.java:387)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:122)
```

Is it possible to have such custom values in the properties file

Comment: where did you found property `masterUsername`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use it in your changeSets as property, e.g.

```
 <changeSet ...>
   <sql>
     INSERT INTO myTab(some_column) VALUES ('${masterUsername}')
   </sql>
 </changeSet>
```

then try putting this into your liquibase.properties:

```
parameter.masterUsername=your_desired_value
```

As an alternative, you can pass these on the command line as Java properties, e.g.

```
liquibase update ... -DmasterUsername=your_desired_value
```

See http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html and http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html for details.