# Liquibase Parameters not being read in changelog from environment variables

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I am trying to get some parameters from environment varibles into liquibase_data.properties which read into my changelog file but not having much success.

The following is my liquibase_data.properties file:

```
db1.name=${DB1_HOSTNAME}
db2.name=${DB2_HOSTNAME}
```

Changelog File:

```
<property  name="db.properties"  file="liquibase_data.properties"/>

<changeSet author="dmohanpuria (generated)" id="1710307015865-2">
<insert tableName="dext_datasource_detail">
<column name="dade_id" valueNumeric="1"/>
<column name="dade_client_id" valueNumeric="1"/>
<column name="**dade_source_url**" value=**"${db1.name}"**/>
<column name="dade_recovery_url"/>
<column name="dade_driver_class_name" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
<column name="dade_dialect" value="MSSQL"/>
</insert>
</changeSet>
```

The problem is dade_source_url is always coming back as the literal value "${DB1_HOSTNAME}" and not the value getting passed in environment variables. The reason I need this is because this database source url changes from environment to environment.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems similar to [custom properties in liquibase.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916982/custom-properties-in-liquibase-properties-file) .
You could also use **DB1_HOSTNAME** directly in your changelog as:

```
<column name="dade_source_url" value="${DB1_HOSTNAME }"/>
```

You don't need to pass it to a properties file, you just use it directly.